# create Menu and Sub menu recursively in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, menu, extjs3

Is there way i can create Menu and Submenu recursivesly like tree node creation in Treepanel Extjs

Say i have empty menu items

I read xml input for constructing a Menu and Submenu

my xml look like

```
<r>
<sub>
 <sub1>
  <sub 1.1/>
  <sub 1.1.1/>
</sub1>
<sub2/>
<sub3>
<sub 3.1>
<sub 3.1.1>
</sub3>
</r>
```

xml may go any depth ,please provide suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
buildHelpMenuItems: function () {

                var menuItemNodes = Ext.DomQuery.jsSelect('SUB', me.responseXML),
                mb = (toolbarHlpMenu) ? toolbarHlpMenu.menu : '',
                menu,
                menuArray = [];
                newMenuArray = [];
                if(menuItemNodes.length ==0 || !mb)
                    return;
                function buildMenuItem(node, scope) {
                    var menuitem = {};
                    menuitem.text = (node.attributes.getNamedItem('LABEL')) ? node.attributes.getNamedItem('LABEL').nodeValue : '';
                    menuitem.iconCls = (node.attributes.getNamedItem('clsName')) ? node.attributes.getNamedItem('clsName').nodeValue : '';
                    menuitem.url = (node.attributes.getNamedItem('URL')) ? node.attributes.getNamedItem('URL').nodeValue : '';
                    menuitem.handler = scope.helpMenuHandler;
                    menuitem.hidden = (node.attributes.getNamedItem('HIDDEN')) ? eval(node.attributes.getNamedItem('HIDDEN').nodeValue) : false;
                    menuitem.type = (node.attributes.getNamedItem('TYPE')) ? node.attributes.getNamedItem('TYPE').nodeValue : '';
                    return menuitem;
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < menuItemNodes.length; i++) {
                    var node = menuItemNodes[i];
                    menuItem = buildMenuItem(node,me);
                    if (!Ext.isEmpty(node.parentNode.getAttribute('LABEL'))) {
                        menuItem.parentEl = node.parentNode.getAttribute('LABEL');
                    } else {
                        menuItem.parentEl = "";
                    }
                    menuArray.push(menuItem);
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < menuArray.length; i++) {
                    var menuItem = menuArray[i];
                    if (menuItem.parentEl == "") {
                        newMenuArray.push(menuItem);
                    } else {
                        var parentEl = Ext.Array.findBy(menuArray, function (item) {
                                return (item.text == menuItem.parentEl);
                            });
                        if (Ext.isEmpty(parentEl.menu)) {
                            parentEl.menu = [];
                            parentEl.menu.push(menuItem);
                        } else {
                            parentEl.menu.push(menuItem);
                        }
                    }
                }
                mb.add(newMenuArray);

        },
```

this Code tested in Extjs 4.2